# Parallel states with Python's transitions package?

Tags: python-3.x, state-machine

Is it possible to implement [parallel states](https://statecharts.github.io/glossary/parallel-state.html) with Python's [transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement parallel states with Python's transitions. See the [documentation](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) and search for "parallel".
You will need to use the HierarchicalMachine as shown

```
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalGraphMachine
```

An example is provided there too:

```
states = ['A', 'B', {'name': 'C', 
          'parallel': [{'name': '1', 'children': ['a','b','c'], 'initial':'a',
          'transitions': [['go', 'a', 'b']]},
                       {'name': '2', 'children': ['x','y','z'], 'initial':'z'}],
          'transitions': [['go', '2_z', '2_x']]}]
```

In order to access sub-states, you can refer to them by the {parent_child} name. For instance "C_2" would be state "2" within state "C".